# Free a binary tree without using recursion or allocating memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, tree, kernel

As the title says, the objective is to free a binary tree without using the stack or allocating memory.
This was required for a kernel module where resources were limited.

Result has a complexity of \$ O \left( n \right) \$.

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T     data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

// Utility function to find the bottom left
// Of the tree (because that has a NULL left
// pointer that we can use to store information.
Node* findBottomLeft(Node* t)
{
    while(t->left != NULL)
    {
        t = t->left;
    }
    return t;
}

void freeTree(Node* t)
{
    if (t == NULL)
    {   return;
    }

    // Points at the bottom left node.
    // Any right nodes are added to the bottom left as we go down
    // this progressively flattens the tree into a list as we go.    
    Node* bottomLeft    = findBottomLeft(t);


    while(t != NULL)
    {
        // Technically we don't need the if (it works fine without)
        // But it makes the code easier to reason about with it here.
        if (t->right != NULL)
        {
            bottomLeft->left = t->right;
            bottomLeft = findBottomLeft(bottomLeft);
        }
        // Now just free the curent node
        Node*   old = t;
        t = t->left;
        delete old;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks mostly C-ish. Using `unique_ptr` and the like would be more idiomatic and exception safe, but as you are in a kernel environment, exceptions are not allowed and your recursion requirement rules out the use of `unique_ptr`. (Then again I am wondering why you are programming C++ in the (supposedly Linux-)kernel)

Comment: @Nobody: You missed the point. using unique_ptr would break the whole concept of not using recursion. Who said Linux and this kernal supports exceptions.

Comment: That is just what I said :) I just wanted to point out that without these restrictions that would be the path to follow. Hence, I made it only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I can't understand what the question is. Can you make it explicit?

Comment: I like it as it is. And it's already O(n), so you can't get better than that for this. Quick note though, this doesn't compile on Visual Studio 2012, but I doubt that portability is all that important to you.

Comment: Actually I was first shown this code on the core of the Windows kernel so I should have written it to be portable. Where is it breaking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## function missing templates

I'm sure you're aware, but the functions need the same templating as the `Node` such that `void freeTree(Node* t)` becomes:

```
template<typename T>
void freeTree(Node<T>* t)
```

## slight reduction in memory use

You could slightly reduce the stack used by essentially inlining the function call to `findBottomLeft`.  The rewritten function now looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void freeTree(Node<T>* t)
{
    // bl points at the bottom left node.
    // Any right nodes from t are added to the bottom left as we go down.
    // This progressively flattens the tree into a list as we go.    
    Node<T> *bl;
    for(bl=t ; bl != nullptr && bl->left != nullptr; bl=bl->left);

    while(t != nullptr)
    {
        // body of for loop deliberately empty
        for (bl->left = t->right; bl != nullptr && bl->left != nullptr; bl=bl->left);
        Node<T>*   old = t;
        // Now just free the curent node
        t = t->left;
        delete old;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `nullptr` rather than `NULL` here which is a C++11 feature.  If you're not using a C++11 compliant compiler, you can simply use `NULL` for each of those instances.

Also, I've eliminated the early return in the case that `t` was equal to `NULL` in the original because this case is handled correctly by the `for` loop and `while` loop.

It's also important to realize that the body of the for loop is deliberately empty.  Some people dislike having a `for` loop with just a semicolon at the end, but I think it's not a problem if there is a comment pointing it out.

Comment: Comment is correct. The call to `findBottomLeft()` is not going to de-refernece a NULL if t->right is NULL.

Comment: inlining is a job for the compiler. As a human my job is to write easy to read code.

Comment: The test `bl != nullptr` should be removed from the loop / inner-loop again, and replaced by the test `t != nullptr` found at the start of the function in the original, for best performance.

Comment: A nice way to get around the empty `for` loop is to use `continue` as the loop body.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Some coding standards forbid the use of `continue`, but there's nothing technically wrong with your suggestion in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you could build your tree using `std::map`, `std::set` or Boost graph library. They have allocators which you could use to allocate from a single pre-allocated block of memory. Your non-recursive free then becomes simply freeing the pre-allocated block. I'm not saying this is a simple approach nor the best for general work but maybe it meets your requirements.

Comment: While this sounds like a good suggestion, I feel like your answer is missing something.

Comment: This sounds like a good response but I think maybe it is missing a description of what my answer is missing. Or have I missed your point?

Comment: It is missing a description of what is missing because I just have a general feeling. I would suggest some code, but It could be just noise. I have no clear idea of what you could do, I was just trying to "warn" you.